# Accounts & Contacts Relationship - Where Defined?

Tags: relationships

In the schema builder diagram, there is a 1:M lookup relationship between Accounts and Contacts.

However, I cannot find where this lookup relationship is defined. Is it under the Customise/Accounts/Fields page ? I could not find it.

I want to see how Salesforce has implemented this relationship.

Thanks in advance for your input

Answer (score 1):

Contact is considered to be a Master-Detail relationship with Account being the Master and Contact being on the detail or child side of Account. It's not explicitly stated because Salesforce allows you to create Contacts that have no related AccountId and thus are not parented to a Master record (Account), yet that is the nature of their relationship.

I hope this helps explain the relationship and how it works within Salesforce as it can be confusing when one first learns to work with it. As a "best practice", it's always wise to create a new Contact from the Account screen to make certain the Contact gets related to the Account. Salesforce's "Quick Create" menu doesn't enforce this relationship as there are some contacts one might have that are unrelated to a business account that one might want to keep in their list of contacts that are more of a personal or "utility" nature.

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. However, where has Salesforce defined this relationship. I thought that I could see a relationship field of Lookup or Master-Detail type in the Contact object. But look hard I did - I could not find it anywhere.

Comment: Contact has a field on it called AccountId.